# importing csv file into mysql and changing date time format at same time

Tags: php, mysql, import, explode, datetime-format

I have a script which imports a csv file into a MySQL table using explode to separate the fields. my last field in the csv file is a date time field but in the incorrect format as per image below:
[image]

I want to use the below code to insert the csv into MySQL and change the format of the last column from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm to the MySQL format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Existing working script (just doesn't import date time field as format is wrong):

```
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "LoadsOverWB.csv";
foreach(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    /************************************
    This line escapes the special character. remove it if entries are already escaped in the csv file
    ************************************/
    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
    /*************************************/

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

    if($addauto)
        $query = "replace into $databasetable(loadnumber,weighbillnumber,VehicleRegistration,haulier,vehicleweight,rolledproductkg,hegrosskg,roofinhkg,nonmetalkg,wbtotalkg,datetime) values('','$linemysql');";
    else
        $query = "replace into $databasetable(loadnumber,weighbillnumber,VehicleRegistration,haulier,vehicleweight,rolledproductkg,hegrosskg,roofinhkg,nonmetalkg,wbtotalkg,datetime) values('$linemysql');";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";

    @mysql_query($query);
}
```

Thanks in advance as always, much appreciated.

Comment: use date function of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two lines after exploding

```
$key    =   count($linearray);
$linearray[$key - 1]    =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($linearray[$key - 1]));

$linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
```

Also before inserting print_r the result to see if the format has been changed.

EDITS :

Looking at the library you are using i assume the last index of each row is your date column(TIME OVER WEB). So i am count the length of array and count - 1 gives me the last index so than i am applying php date function.
    date('format',strtotime(datevalue))
strtotime converts the string given to numbers like 32431234 and then date function takes tow parameters. Format and number. I am sure that's enough for you to understand.

Comment: Thanks raheel, woks perfectly but I am not sure why, can you elaborate a little on the reason this works? Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should check out [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). You will get each row into an array, and be able to process it a lot better.

And to answer your question, you need to format the date.

```
$date = $linearray['date']; // or what key your date has
$date = date('Y-M-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```